# Can I get the Visual Studio 2008 report designer to look like the Visual Studio 2005 report designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I liked the grid points and the visible separation of the header/body/footer of the report on the design surface or vs2005.

I hate the vs2008 report designer which is just a blank canvas with no grid lines/points and separation of header/body/footer...

Comment: Why you trying to go back?  Run away from 05 my friend, run away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid lines are gone from VS 2008. The alignment indicators seem to have "replaced" the functionality.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/c2649ef7-048c-4243-92f6-600bd13d5baf

Answer (score 1):

I use VS2008 and the report designer shows the grid points and the visible separation of the Header/Body/Footer.

Have you tried adjusting the report properties from the report menu? Make sure 'Draw Grid' is checked and that the grid spacing is 0.25cm. That's how mine is set up (by default).

Answer (score 0):

"Draw Grid" isn't in the Report>Report Properties menu in VS 2008. It is in VS 2005 though.

I also can't display the grid in report desgner in VS 2008 - I've tried every combination of settings/ restarting the app to no avail. I'd also like the ruler to appear by default whenever I open a form but can't seem to find a setting for that either.